# Dealing with legacy tensorflow without GPU support

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, gpu

Code:

```
import os
os.envirion['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

c = np.array([-40, -10, -0, 8, 15, 22, 38])
f = np.array([-40, 14, 32, 46, 59, 72, 100])

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=1,input_shape=(1,), activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))

history = model.fit(c, f, epochs=500, verbose=0)

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

print(model.get_weights())
```

I don't need CUDA to work (and I can't install it on amd) and the CPU is enough. Installed tensorflow 1.15 without GPU support, the first 2 lines of code should seem to hide the warning that there is no CUDA, but nothing works with them at all:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/krist/PycharmProjects/newpy/exam1.py", line 2, in <module>
    os.envirion['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'envirion'
```

It works without them, but there are a lot of warnings:

```
    2021-02-13 15:06:56.460608: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found
2021-02-13 15:06:56.460848: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\krist\miniconda3\envs\newpy\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py:1630: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
2021-02-13 15:06:58.537138: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-02-13 15:06:59.115843: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1650 major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.56
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2021-02-13 15:06:59.117006: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found
2021-02-13 15:06:59.117956: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_100.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_100.dll not found
2021-02-13 15:06:59.118915: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_100.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_100.dll not found
2021-02-13 15:06:59.119933: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_100.dll'; dlerror: curand64_100.dll not found
2021-02-13 15:06:59.120970: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_100.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_100.dll not found
2021-02-13 15:06:59.122001: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_100.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_100.dll not found
2021-02-13 15:06:59.122953: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_7.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_7.dll not found
2021-02-13 15:06:59.123152: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1641] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-02-13 15:06:59.123868: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2021-02-13 15:06:59.201911: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-02-13 15:06:59.202095: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]
```

It kind of says here that tensorflow is deprecated and will be removed in the future, how long can I still work with this version and how can I remove all these warnings?

Comment: Some reading comprehension, it does not say that tensorflow itself is deprecated, only that some function inside it is. And your first error is because you misspelled os.environ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are executing code in `TF 1.15`, you are getting above deprecated warning. It will resolved once you upgrade to `Tensorflow 2.x`.

> AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'envirion'

It can be resolved if you can correct spell to [environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os#os.environ)

Working code as shown below

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam


c = np.array([-40, -10, -0, 8, 15, 22, 38])
f = np.array([-40, 14, 32, 46, 59, 72, 100])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=1,input_shape=(1,), activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer= Adam(0.1))

history = model.fit(c, f, epochs=500, verbose=0)

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
print(model.get_weights())
```